# JavaFX SVGPath very slow with a large content

Tags: java, svg, javafx

I am working with a large array of dots (4096x256) to be displayed as an image in a JavaFX application. I started with a BMP image built from the 2D array of dots, but the zooming operation produced a blurred image on screen. So, I decided to use SVGPath to draw my image which now zooms in properly (no blur) with a simple SVGPath content, but becomes veeeeeery slow when it comes to displaying a checkerboard of two colors, probably because the SVGPath content is so large for fail bits information, as shown in my code.
Is there an efficient way to achieve this? By efficient, I mean fast execution time while keeping the pixel-sharp zooming effect.

```
public Group createImage(final int width, final int height, final int boxIdx)
  {
   // assuming that pass data bits are more numerous than others, we can
   // start by drawing full green colored lines
   StringBuilder svgPass = new StringBuilder();
   for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
   {
    svgPass.append("M0,");
    svgPass.append(Integer.toString(y));
    svgPass.append(" ");
    svgPass.append("L0,");
    svgPass.append(Integer.toString(y));
    svgPass.append(" ");
    svgPass.append(Integer.toString(width - 1));
    svgPass.append(",");
    svgPass.append(Integer.toString(y));
    svgPass.append(" z");
   }

   SVGPath imgPass = new SVGPath();
   imgPass.setContent(svgPass.toString());
   imgPass.setStrokeLineJoin(StrokeLineJoin.BEVEL);
   imgPass.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
   imgPass.setStrokeWidth(1);

   // fail data bits
   StringBuilder svgFail = new StringBuilder();
   Bit[][] bits = WordLineManager.getInstance().getBlocksMap().get(boxIdx);

   for (int y = 0; y < bits.length; y++)
   {
    for (int x = 0; x < bits[0].length; x++)
    {
     if (bits[y][x].getNature() == BitNature.DATA && !bits[y][x].getStatus())
     {
         svgFail.append("M");
         svgFail.append(Integer.toString(x));
         svgFail.append(",");
         svgFail.append(Integer.toString(y));
         svgFail.append(" ");
         svgFail.append("L");
         svgFail.append(Integer.toString(x));
         svgFail.append(",");
         svgFail.append(Integer.toString(y));
         svgFail.append(" ");
         svgFail.append(Integer.toString(x + 1));
         svgFail.append(",");
         svgFail.append(Integer.toString(y));
         svgFail.append(" z");
     }
    }
   }

   SVGPath imgFail = new SVGPath();
   imgFail.setContent(svgFail.toString());
   imgFail.setStrokeLineJoin(StrokeLineJoin.BEVEL);
   imgFail.setStroke(Color.RED);
   imgFail.setStrokeWidth(1);

   return new Group(imgPass, imgFail);
  }
```

Comment: You'd probably see an improvement in performance by using a `Canvas` and `GraphicsContext.appendSvgPath` rather than `SVGPath`.

Comment: To pinpoint the problem I would recommend to introduce [StopWatch](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/time/StopWatch.html) to see which block is the slowest. Example - [here](https://kodejava.org/calculate-timings-using-commons-lang-stopwatch/)

Comment: You are right @hudsonb things go faster, but I fall back in the blurry image issue I met with BMP images.